# Comparing Enum Value With Integer - Assert.AreEqual

Tags: c#, enums, nunit

I have the following test for an enum:

```
[TestCase]
public void NoneIsDefaultTest()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(0, Command.None);
}
```

The idea is to ensure that no additions to the enum change the default value. However, the test fails with:

```
Expected: 0
But was:  None
```

Is Assert.AreEqual automatically applying .ToString()? How can I avoid this?

**Edit**:
enum definition:

```
internal enum Command { None = 0, Build, Config, Reconfig, Help, Version }
```

Comment: I removed the comment, because I just tested it, you were right, and the answer below is absolutely correct, just cast to int.

Comment: Interesting behavior of `AreEqual` though... if you do `Console.WriteLine(0 == Command.None);` it outputs `True`.  But I think `AreEqual` calls `actual.Equals(expected)`.

Comment: @EvanL - There is an implicit conversion from the literal `0` to any enum type, so that is a special case. It does not work for other values, e.g. `1 == Command.Build` will not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting to int should be fine:

```
Assert.AreEqual(0, (int)Command.None);
```

Answer (score 5):

`AreEqual` is not using `ToString` for the comparison, only when formatting the error message. Enums form a type distinct from the underlying value type, so the comparison `0.Equals(Command.None)` returns false, since the enum value is not an int.

Answer (score 1):

Casting to an int works, but if all you want to test is the default value (which is what was behind my question), you can use the default keyword:

```
[TestCase]
public void NoneIsDefaultTest()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(default(Command), Command.None);
}
```

It also has an intuitive feel, if the default itself is really what you're testing.